# In Perl POD, what is the proper way to link to an internal function?

Tags: perl, documentation, perl-pod

The [perlpod](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod) documentation says you can `L<link to something>` but it does not indicate the proper way to reference a Perl-core function (or if it does, it wasn't obvious to me).

Specifically, I want to link to what is shown by `perldoc -f wantarray`.  What is the proper way to `L<...>` link to it so it will take you to the `wantarray` documentation when you click on the link from MetaCPAN and other POD viewers that follow links?

(Note that `wantarray` is just a built-in Perl function like `print` or `open`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best I find is to bring up the manual pages (perldoc) on CPAN

```
L<perlfunc/wantarray>

L<File::Find>

L<perlop>

L<perlsyn/"For Loops">
```

These bring up pages on CPAN: [wantarray](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#wantarray), [File::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find), [perlop](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlop), and ["For Loops" in perlsyn](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlsyn#For-Loops). They are linked on their `perldoc` pages and seem to be exactly the same (except for the handy table of contents that `perldoc` pages may have). Or use `L<wantarray|perlfunc/wantarray>`, but try it as it stands first with its [inferred link text](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpodspec#Second:).

Find the syntax for (possible) other kinds of pages by finding them on [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org) and using the link "CPAN" on top of their page.

These are tested and processed as described using CPAN's [POD renderer (pod2html)](https://metacpan.org/pod2html) since the question is about CPAN content.

If these CPAN hosted pages don't cut it then all I can see is to use the URL for `perldoc` pages.

---

Btw, UNIX man pages work right out of docs:

```
L<crontab(5)>
```

This brings up http://man.he.net/man5/crontab

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the full URL to the [wantarray](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray) function:

```
L<wantarray|https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray>
```

---

The above works and you can easily try it out on the [metacpan POD Renderer](https://metacpan.org/pod2html)

Answer (score 1):

It's in [perlpod](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod#Formatting-Codes) as the `L<name/sec>` form. [perlpodspec](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpodspec) has some more details.

For example, `wantarray` is the section in the `perlfunc` page name. You'd write `L<perlfunc/wantarray>`. If you want a Perl special variable `$^V`, you'd write `L<perlvar/$^V>`. You have to know where things are in the docs (and that's not always obvious).

Realize that the particular Pod processor will output some phrase, and you should account for that in your expected sentence. This is the phrase that comes out of `Pod::Text`:

> "wantarray" in perlfunc

You want to take into account that extra "in perlfunc" that shows up.

There are other ways to link, though, as you've seen in the other answers.